# How to distinguish between ARM code and Thumb code with static analysis

Tags: arm, static-analysis, disassembly, thumb

I know that the Thumb code consists of 16 bits, and the ARM code consists of 32 bits. But is there a way to see the specific offsets in the file and tell whether the instruction is ARM code or Thumb code? When implementing the disassembler, I wonder how I can distinguish between ARM code and Thumb code.

Comment: like any other disassembler you have to disassemble in execution order.  And as with most instruction sets it is imperfect, even if you emulate, but at times you have to emulate or do a deeper analysis to correctly disassemble.  If you follow the code path you can determine thumb from arm for some percentage of the code, the rest you have to leave as data and figure out by hand or through emulation.

Comment: compiled code is of course much easier, but if you run into some hand written assembly and worse, someone trying to defeat a disassembler, your chances go down.  that doesnt mean you shouldnt try.

Comment: and before anyone jumps in yes thumb2 is 16 bit as well, these are individual decoded 16 bit chunks in that mode, thumb2 extensions are formerly undefined 16 bit instructions that are now variable length (in this case an additional 16 bits is tacked on).  this of course making the disassembly that much harder.

Comment: if it was pure arm, or pure pre-thumb2 thumb, and nothing mixed then you could just linearly blast through as the instructions have to be aligned, and you can disassemble the data or call it unknown and keep going as you will eventually pick back up in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Most arbitrary sequences of words would represent both valid ARM instructions and valid pairs of Thumb instructions.  In most cases, there would thus be no 100% reliable way to distinguish between the two unless one could identify code which was known to execute, and which would perform a BX or BLX with a known branch target (in which case the LSB of the target would distinguish ARM or Thumb code).

From a heuristic perspective, however, the distribution of bit patterns found in typical code would be very different in ARM and Thumb code.  For example, even if one didn't know anything about any particular instructions, if one simply listed out the contents of every 32-bit word as an 8-digit hex number, one per line, and observed the distribution of digit values in each column, all eight columns would likely yield different distributions with ARM code, but the first four columns would have a distribution similar to the last four when given Thumb code.  This effect would generally be especially pronounced if one were to look at the "condition code" column, since most instructions don't specify a condition code.

Examining the bit patterns associated with particular instructions would likely allow a scanner to identify constructs that wouldn't make much sense on the ARM but would make sense on the Thumb, or vice versa, but even simple numerical distribution may be adequate in many situations.